# error - unhandledRejection: ReferenceError: self is not defined in next js App

Tags: typescript, heroku, next.js, firebase-notifications

**I tried deploying my nextjs app but as we know next js won't be deployed if we have even a single warning. I used firebase notifications in my next app and then I started getting this reference error**

error - unhandledRejection: ReferenceError: self is not defined
at isSupported (C:\Users\rehas\3D Objects\INTERN\SUPPLYS DEPLOYED\node_modules\firebase\node_modules@firebase\messaging\dist\index.cjs.js:1711:5)
at Component.factoryMethod [as instanceFactory] (C:\Users\rehas\3D Objects\INTERN\SUPPLYS DEPLOYED\node_modules\firebase\node_modules@firebase\messaging\dist\dist\index.cjs.js:1694:10)                                                                                                                                       \index.cjs.j
at Provider.getOrInitializeService (C:\Users\rehas\3D Objects\INTERN\SUPPLYS DEPLOYED\node_modules@firebase\component\dist\index.cjs.js:222:39)
at Provider.getImmediate (C:\Users\rehas\3D Objects\INTERN\SUPPLYS DEPLOYED\node_modules@firebase\component\dist\index.cjs.js:120:33)
at FirebaseAppImpl._getService (C:\Users\rehas\3D Objects\INTERN\SUPPLYS DEPLOYED\node_modules@firebase\app\dist\index.node.cjs.js:230:49)
at FirebaseAppImpl.firebaseAppImpl. [as messaging] (C:\Users\rehas\3D Objects\INTERN\SUPPLYS DEPLOYED\node_modules@firebase\app\dist\index.node.cjse.cjs.js:442:39)                                                                                                                                                  .js:442:39)
at Object.serviceNamespace [as messaging] (C:\Users\rehas\3D Objects\INTERN\SUPPLYS DEPLOYED\node_modules@firebase\app\dist\index.node.cjs.js:422:45)
at Module../src/pages/firebase.js (C:\Users\rehas\3D Objects\INTERN\SUPPLYS DEPLOYED.next\server\src_pages_firebase_js.js:41:71)
at Function.**webpack_require** (C:\Users\rehas\3D Objects\INTERN\SUPPLYS DEPLOYED.next\server\webpack-runtime.js:25:43)
at runMicrotasks ()

**HEROKU ERROR:**
[BUILD ERROR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gkPOb.png)

Comment: Having the exact same for many of my apps updated to Nextjs 12. Just opened this issue https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/32014

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. [Please don't post screenshots of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/354577). They can't be searched or copied, or even consumed by users of adaptive technologies like screen readers. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question. If you select it and click the `{}` button or Ctrl+K the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code.